# Interrupt running thread

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I'm just improvising with Thread cancellation using thread interruption. Although in my code both threads are stopped, It looks like I'm not catching `InterruptedException`  I' just wonder why?

Producer:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable{

    private BlockingQueue<String> queue ;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            try {

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                queue.put("Hello");
            } 
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interupting Producer");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    BlockingQueue<String> queue;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
        super();
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        String s;
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                s = queue.take();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Consumer Interupted");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

and now Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

    Thread producerThread = new Thread(new Producer(queue));
    Thread consumerThread = new Thread(new Consumer(queue));
    producerThread.start();
    consumerThread.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } finally {
        producerThread.interrupt();
        consumerThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Although the threads stop, I can't realize why `InterruptedException` is not cough. 
It supposed to print interruption message inside catch block but nothing is printed

Comment: This probably shouldn't have the `java-ee` tag...

Comment: How you think? Can the thread which interrupted checks status itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unbounded queue, hence neither the producer nor the consumer are ever blocked on the queue. Hence, no operation that could throw InterruptedException is interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is en example of interruption :

public class TestThread1 implements Runnable {

```
public void run() {
    while(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() == false) {
        System.out.println("dans la boucle");

        //on simule une courte pause

        for(int k=0; k<100000000; k++);

        System.out.println("Thread isInterrupted = " + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new TestThread1());
    t.start();

    //on laisse le temps à l'autre Thread de se lancer
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    } catch(InterruptedException e) {}

    System.out.println("interruption du thread");
    t.interrupt();
}
```

}

The result of the execution is :

> dans la boucle
>
> Thread isInterrupted = false
>
> dans la boucle
>
> interruption du thread
>
> Thread isInterrupted = true